# How to download an updated file by admin in Django

Tags: python, django, download

what i am trying to do is:

- Admin uploads a PDF file from admin panel. (1)
- It needs to go to the specified template. (2)
- And it should be downloaded by pressing download button in the template.

So here are codes:

(1)

```
class Reports(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="File Name")
report = models.FileField()
```

(2)

```
<tr>
   <td>"File Name must be showed in here"</td>
   <td class="text-center">PDF</td>
   <td class="text-center lang-tr-src"><a href="What way should i give here?" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i></a></td>
   <td class="text-center lang-en-src"><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

In the website there will be one report for every month. I want to list them in the template and make them downloadable.
Should i write a view for that(if yes how it should be?) or what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every single data you want to show to your template you need write it in your views.py, so this case is so specefic.

views.py:

```py
def your_view_name(request):
    reports = Reports.objects.all()
    context = {
     'reports': reports
     }
    return render(request, 'your_template.html', context)
```

Then make a url for your view in urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.your_view_name, name='your_url_name')
     ]
```

Your template:

```html
<tr>
       {% for obj in reports %}
       <td>{{ obj.name }}</td>
       <td class="text-center">PDF</td>
       <td class="text-center lang-tr-src"><a href="{{ obj.report.url }}" Download 
       target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i></a></td>
       <td class="text-center lang-en-src"><a href="" target="_blank"><i 
       class="fas fa-file-download"></i></a></td>
       {% endfor %}
  </tr>
```

Comment: Calling variables in template from view uses `{{ v }}` not `{% v %}`

Comment: @Moha369 yes right, I got distracted, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

create a new view firstly.

```
def report_view(request):
    context = {}
    reports= Reports.objects.all()
    context['reports'] = reports
    return render(request, "pages/report.html", context)
```

create an url for this view in urls.py

```
path('reports', report_view, name='report_view'),
```

in your template create forloop for this context like below:

```
{% for report in reports %} 
<tr>
   <td>"File Name must be showed in here"</td>
   <td class="text-center">PDF</td>
   <td class="text-center lang-tr-src"><a href="report.report " target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i></a></td>
   <td class="text-center lang-en-src"><a href="" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-file-download"></i></a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```